# (Internal Server Error) on django web push notifications with heroku

Tags: django, api, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I'm building a messages app where a user can send incognito messages so the reciever wouldn't know who send the message.. any way just needed to implement push notifications so whenever new message come to a user he receives a push notificatoin
I've followed [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-from-django-applications) which i found after some searching and it worked perfect for me on the local host ,how ever when i tried to deploy my app on heroku that didn't work

- **things I've faced**

1- error on the front end
first time i tried it out it worked perfect but just as I reloaded the page I found this error in the console

> registerSW.js:66 POST https://stalker-rat.herokuapp.com/webpush/save_information 500 (Internal Server Error)

this 66 line is responsible for saving the information about the registered service worker I think , but this caused problems as the service worker was already saved , i thought that the browser would handle this .. any way this is my code

```
 const res = await fetch('/webpush/save_information', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        
    },
    credentials: "include"
});
```

at first i thought this was some thing about the csrftoken but adding it to the post request didn't do any thing

2. error on the back end
   trying to send my self a message from a different account gave me a forbidden 403 error or

> ProgrammingError at /user/14/
> relation "webpush_pushinformation" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...."auth", "webpush_subscriptioninfo"."p256dh" FROM "webpush_p...

actually I don't understand any of these so after about five hours searching I couldn't find any useful info

Dear Django developers , I'm a beginner so please don't blame me if this was a very easy question or even a stupid one , thanks for understanding..

Answer (score 1):

here am i answering my own question ..
the solution was to migrate my database
the problem was that after adding webpush to installed apps i migrated it locally but never done this on heroku , sorry for wasting your time for such a small mistake